# query data in a database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to retrieve data from my client db, using a html form.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code, this php code to collect data from my database and return the answer. I am very new to html/ php any help appreciated.

```
   <?php
      echo $_POST['term']; 
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db ("client");
 $term = $_POST['term'];
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from `client` where first_name like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo 'ID: '.$row['ID'];
    echo '<br/> First Name: '.$row['first_name'];
    echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['last_name'];
    echo '<br/> Phone: '.$row['Phone'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }




?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Notice: Undefined index: term in C:\xampp\htdocs\getdata.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: term in C:\xampp\htdocs\getdata.php on line 22

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\getdata.php on line 24

still getting the above notice

Comment: Well, for one, SQL injection. For two, the deprecated mysql_ function calls. And you're the third with these two problems today, only who I have seen. When does this stop?

Answer (score 2):

This is your immediate problem:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from 'client' where first_name like '%$term%'");
```

The quoting around the table name `client` is incorrect. Use backticks for this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `client` where first_name like '%$term%'");
```

And you should protect yourself:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `client` where first_name like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%'");
```

But seriously, please promise to read up on **SQL injection**, and **don't use mysql_ functions** anymore!

**USE PDO please**

Read these:

- [SELECT with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15410966/1667004)
- [INSERT with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390836/1667004)

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying about MySQL and pdo etc, but the problem a lot of us that a learning this stuff is that if you are given old stuff to learn with, old MySQL phpmyadmin and old code, how do we keep up with you guys. I just need a html page written in Notepad++ from books that are 10year old. that gets the data in a my phpmyadmin database that is in xampp 1.8. to work, it will never go live or be used.

Comment: @pitbull10 Exactly this is why I - and fellow SOers - care... I might have overreagated the whole issue, I'm just shocked so few people know about these things... Ok, literature might be old - but there is a reason I only buy specific books, and learn the rest online as much as possible. I advise everybody to do the same, as some books can get obsolete the minute they hit the shelves. Sorry, if I sounded harsh, my patience these days is not as it used to be...

Comment: what I am talking about is what UNI's are teaching old stuff from old software and old books.

Comment: @pitbull10 I understand this, and I'm sad about that (I used to teach too on a university a few years ago)... I think you should tell your tutors these issues, but that might result in "unwanted consequences"... Some tutors don't like students being smarter than them.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ppeterka's solutions, there's also a missing quotation mark amd semi colon just before the closure of your while loop

```
echo '<br/><br/>
}
```

should read

```
echo '<br/><br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi from a quick look at it, i would say, the error is in the MySQL query itself.
You are using single quotes around the table name and i do not think that is correct. try using no quotes whatsoever or use the single "backquote" or what you call it - the symbol: `

Comment: If your code still does not work, i would suggest to insert:
`var_dump($_POST);`
somwehere on the beginning of your code to see what you actually have in your $_POST field. You may be sending the data to yourself using $_GET or you may have misspelled the name of the POST variable. From which comes the fact that $sql is FALSE for the resulting SQL query is invalid ($_POST['term'] seems to be undefined)